# MySQL Workbench schema synchronization causing error 1064

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to try to create a schema for my database. When I try to sync it up to the server, I'm getting an error 1064. Here's the full log:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `buildings_rel`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bu' at line 10
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rentals`.`apartments` (
          `beds` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `baths` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `area` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `price_min` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `price_max` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `available_now` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
          `building_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          INDEX `buildings_rel_idx` (`building_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          CONSTRAINT `buildings_rel`
            FOREIGN KEY (`building_id`)
            REFERENCES `rentals`.`buildings` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

I don't really know SQL so I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly is wrong here. I expected the Workbench to create correct code, I'm a little surprised that it seems to be this glitchy. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The `VISIBLE` option for indexes is new to MySQL 8.0. If you're using an older version of MySQL, you shouldn't use that option.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a new version of Workbench with an older MySQL. Maybe there's some way to tell it what version of MySQL you're using, so it produces compatible code.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! As some of the commentors said, I had to set a different target version in the MySQL Workbench settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the Default Target MySQL Version to match your mysql version.

```
Home -> Edit -> Preferences -> Modeling -> MySQL -> Default Target MySQL Version
```

[image]